# Login with facebook integration (oauth) in an existing php database. Seriously need advice

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0

I am not asking to solve my problem but yes to give me some hints on what should I look for or where should I focus in, in order to get this accomplished.

The problem is my website has his own registration system and I don't know how to join it with facebook's. Visitors should be able to login in both ways, but I have no idea how to do it.

I have followed this guide: http://25labs.com/tutorial-integrate-facebook-connect-to-your-website-using-php-sdk-v-3-x-x-which-uses-graph-api/

But it gives me error in my site, and I can't login using facebook. Any advise on this.
I don't know what I should do yet. My website is written in php.

This is the page where I have tried it:
www.dtraffic.biz/demo/index.php

The tutorial author say I should look the error_log to see which is the problem but when I look this through my cpanel account nothing appears there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here some tips.

You have to add a new field in your userlist database. Example:

```
Database userlist, we add facebook-id field, so:
id    |    nick    |    passw    |    facebook-id
-------------------------------------------------
1     |    Llorx   |    mypass   |
2     |   Llorx12  |    mypass   |
```

And then implement Facebook PHP SDK, you can follow Facebook tutorial.

When an user logins using Facebook, you can ask to create a new account or to link his Facebook account to his existing account in your web, in both cases, you have to fill the database facebook-id with his Facebook id (You can get that info with Facebook graph API after authentication)

```
id    |    nick    |    passw    |    facebook-id
-------------------------------------------------
1     |    Llorx   |    mypass   |    19348317401
2     |   Llorx12  |    mypass   |
```

Now, each time someone logs in using Facebook, you can check if his Facebook id is linked to any account in your database.

Sorry for my bad english :-/

If the error you get is error 500, you have some code wrong written, or maybe Facebook API is throwing an error too, `try catch`ing it and `print_f` it so you know what's happening.

Another tip: Facebook exceptions are called `FacebookApiException` instead of `Exception`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, now I now where I to start messing around. I am looking how to add fields and stuff and it turns out I have to do it like this "ALTER TABLE contacts ADD facebook-id bigint (20) FIRST;" something like that. Which is the name I should use for the field, in the script I have installed I see lines which say "$user = $facebook->getUser();" and in my websites database my user table uses "id" type: bigint(20), user_id: int(11) so what I guess I should do is change $user or $facebook to one of this names? user_id? I am a bit stuck.

Comment: No no, do not change nothing, you only have to add. 'id' and 'user_id' are the identifiers of the user in your website, when someone logs in using your website authentication, 'id' or/and 'user_id' are stored somethere in a session file or something (each website has it's own identification system, you have to understand how is programmed yours) so the website knows who is watching the pages. Your work here is to add a new field, as I told you, then, when a user is authenticated vía Facebook, you have to get Facebook userid the way you told before, then check if that Facebook id is already[..]

Comment: [...]in your database, if it does, then you have to extract 'id' and/or 'user_id' and perform authentication like your website does normally, and that scripting work it's yours, Facebook don't have any script for doing that for you, they only give you the Facebook data of the user browsing your web and your work is adapting it to your needs.

Comment: Ok, now I understand the concept. So I guess I have to add a field in my users table called in the same way facebook's variable. For example fields called $facebook and $user would be all right? Could you refer me to a somewhere where it explains how to make the code to get this variables and insert them in my database. This is like the 3rd day in may live that I do something related to mysql databases. Thanks for your help Jorge.

Comment: So you are new to mysql, ok, I understand. I tell you: when you grab the facebook userid inside a variable you have to query the database searching the user that has that Facebook id linked to, the database is not automatically connected to the php code, you are the one who have to write the code for 'connecting' those variables and the database: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-select-statement-query-data.aspx but before that, you have to update the database and link the Facebook id to the user, so you can find it later.

Comment: Coding is not magic, you must understand what you are doing, and the most important, if you are starting with some language, start learning from below.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have found another tutorial and now, the login button works and I can access facebook through it. I have also added fields in my database usertable for facebook variables. I have @mysqlquery's inserting this variables to my database. I think I can manage better from now on. I have learned a lot. Thanks man.